# sum function with empty array in Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum

I found that once I upgraded my `rails to 5.1.4` . The `sum` function no more working property, in case of an empty array, and an error message `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` is returned. Apart from checking the size of array manually, are there any ways to solve this?

Comment: Can you send me the exact command and the exact error?  `nil.sum` will throw an exception.  `[].sum` will return `0`.  This happens in both Rails 4.2 and Rails 5.1.4.  What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Yes I think this is a very strange behaviour too. While I am using `rails console`, `[].sum` looks perfectly fine and `0` is returned. However, when I tried to run in the web terminal, `[].sum` throws an error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` . I am using rails 5.1.4 under ruby 2.4.1/ 2.4.2 getting the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by web terminal? Are you using `byebug` or another console gem?

Comment: I mean I am running in my server. btw I am using `better_errors`.

Comment: There must be a gem, module, library or other piece of code that is overriding the `sum` method on the `Array` class.  For some reason that override is being applied in your web terminal but not in the rails console.  It may have something do to with a helper, controller or decorator method.  You may want to post your gemfile or explore your gems.  Did you change any gems (besides Rails) when you upgraded?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I would check it first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157328/discussion-between-adam-aiken-and-tom-aranda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) Array with value

myArray = [2,3,nil,5, 0]

myArray.sum { |e| e.to_i }

=> 10
```

2) Empty Array

```
myArray = []

myArray.sum { |e| e.to_i }

=> 0
```

3) Compact method

```
myArray = []
 => [] 
myArray.compact.sum
 => 0 

Returns a copy of self with all nil elements removed. [ "a", nil, "b", nil, "c", nil ].compact #=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Definately a gem, you want to put a breakpoint and step into `[].sum` to see what's up:

```rb
byebug
[].sum
```

For me, first stop was:

1. *[144, 153] in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb*: Nothing to see, `super` is called very quickly and then:
2. *[148, 157]in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/descriptive_statistics-2.5.1/lib/descriptive_statistics/sum.rb*: This is the culprit for me, very old gem (I'm on a 7 year old app). The only use in the project was calculating percentiles, which was easy enough to replace.

TLDR: Maybe it is **descriptive_statistics**, if you don't use that gem, simply step into `[].sum` until you see the error.